# Convert MNIST dataFrame row of 1-D(784) Column to 2D(28x28) using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am reading MNIST like image from a CVS of 784 columns, where each row represents an image. My model needs X_train input in form of 28x28 instead of 784 columns. Since I am new to Pandas and Dataframe, not sure I to do it. It would be really helpful if somebody can help change the shape of the input from 784 colums to 28x28 shape.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after loading data use `numpy.ndarray.reshape()` method:
`x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 28, 28)`

using Pandas is not necessary for this task, numpy alone does it quite well.

Comment: After I did that I started to get following error: `InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
Detected at node 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy`. 
One this to note here is, once the data is read from CSV, its in dataframe, and the reshaping it using numpy converts it to numpy array.

Comment: post more complete code here so that it is more clear what is the shape of the data in the dataframe and how it is used in the model. From loading to error calculation.

Comment: This worked, thanks. The error was due to wrong parameter to input layer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the Pandas `DataFrame` into a NumPy array and then reshape the array:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n_imgs = 60000
n_pix = 28
imgs = np.random.rand(n_imgs, n_pix, n_pix)
df = pd.DataFrame(imgs.reshape(n_imgs, -1))
X_train = df.to_numpy().reshape(n_imgs, n_pix, n_pix)
```